# How to add a checkbox to the CDS view's filter bar

Tags: abap, cds

I would like to add a simple checkbox to a Fiori app based on a CDS view. Clicking it would restrict the data using a parameterized table function that would return "true" or "false" for each row.

I'm unable to find any info on checkboxes in the filter bar. Is this possible using CDS annotations ?

Comment: how do you expose CDS in Fiori? via `sap.m.Table`?

Comment: @Suncatcher: It's a Fiori Elements tile.

Answer (score 2):

Please check the relevant ODATA metadata, if the field of the entity is of type 'Edm.Boolean', in the Fiori, it will automatically rendered as a checkbox. You can also cast the field to ABAP boolean in CDS view if necessary.